# How to do I use the method getBackground.setStroke in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I perform a set stroke in Kotlin?  This does not appear as a method within the background of a button.  Here is what I am trying to achieve in Java:

```
((GradientDrawable) mAllButton.getBackground()).setStroke(1, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: you can always [convert Java to Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started.html#convert-to-kotlin-code)

Comment: (mAllButton.getBackground() as GradientDrawable ).setStroke(1, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Kotlin:

```
(someButton.background as GradientDrawable).setStroke(1, ContextCompat.getColor(context, someColorId))
```

Java:

```
((GradientDrawable)someButton.getBackground()).setStroke(1, ContextCompat.getColor(context, someColorId))
```

P.S. this only works if you initialized your button with a drawable.xml

Comment: The failsafe variant: `(someButton.background as? GradientDrawable)?.setStroke(1, ContextCompat.getColor(context, someColorId))`. This does nothing if the background is not set or is not a GradientDrawable (instead of crashing).